# Pass JQuery Close to a button in my ASPX page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm opening .aspx page B from .aspx page A in a jQuery Dialog box.  Page B is used to send a Sales Rep a quick message.  It contains a Text Box and a Button.  Right now, All I want to do is close this Dialog when I click the button from Page B.

I have the Dialog opening with my page displaying but I don't know how to connect the close event to my button in the page... I'm sure the solution is here someplace but I must be missing it, any ideas?

Thank you in advanced...

Comment: Can you show some of your code?  Considering `Page A` has a dialog box, `Page B` should still be able to anchor onto the page, assuming it isn't an entirely new tab.

Comment: Is Page B an iFrame or loaded into Page A DOM?